# How to add_filter to the_content after a plugin does it

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function that adds a block of html to the top of the_content() wordpress function, however, a wordpress plugin I have also does the same, and it inserts its code ABOVE the block of html I already inserted. But I want my block of html to always be at the top of the_content output.

Is there a way to specify this?

This is my function at the minute (the plugin does it in a similar way, so I assume it's done in order of loading

```
function my_function($content){
    global $post;

    $content = $content . my_function($post) ;
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_function', 9 );
```

the plugin uses:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', array( &$this, 'the_content' ) );
```

I set mine to priority 9, so surely it would be loaded before the plugin's 10 (default)?

Thanks guys.

Comment: A more thorough Pastebin/Gist would be nice.

Comment: Shouldn't that content line read `$content = 'Your content' . $content` if it's intended to appear before the content. Also, your filter should run later, not earlier(so you append content after the plugin has), try a later priority.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you still need help with this but it might be helpful to other people who find your question.

> I set mine to priority 9, so surely it would be loaded before the
>   plugin's 10 (default)?

That is correct, but you want your filter to take effect AFTER the plugin's filter. Currently, your filter inserts a block of HTML into the top of the content section. Then, the plugin filter inserts a block of HTML into the top of the content section, above your previously inserted block. So, you should set the `$priority` filter to a higher value like 20 so that it will occur later and insert the HTML block above all HTML blocks inserted by other filters.